PrimeFaces <p:tabView> with dynamic="true" breaks <p:ajax> in Wildfly – JBoss EAP is working
We have a complex web app which is normally served via RedHat JBoss EAP 7.4 which we are trying to use with Wildfly 26.1.3 (last before javax → jakarta). For the UI we are using Primefaces 13.0.8 (latest).
A rather simple UI with a tab view and some dynamic content fails with Wildfly and I'm still searching for the solution. The same UI works with our EAP installations.
Here is the stripped down version:
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            template="/WEB-INF/templates/minimal.xhtml">

<ui:define name="body">

    <h:form>
        <p:tabView dynamic="true" cache="false">
            <p:tab title="Tab 1">
                <h:inputText>
                    <p:ajax event="keyup" update="time" />
                </h:inputText>
                <h:outputText value="#{developer.timestamp}" id="time" />
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="Tab 2">
                Content
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
    </h:form>

</ui:define>
</ui:composition>

The relevant part is <p:tabView dynamic="true" cache="false"> which we use all over our UI to allow complex tab views to render quickly when needed and not earlier.
With the above example the UI doesn't work (update) with Wildfly so far. But if I simply change from dynamic="true" to dynamic="false" it starts working.
Here is a small GIF of what's supposed to happen if I enter some data.
The timestamp to the right should be updated.
With dynamic="true" it doesn't work.

What am I missing? I've no clue...
Update
It seems related to partial state saving. See https://github.com/da3x/PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING for a reproducible minimal example.

Can you try 13.0.7 and does it work?  And keep going back to 13.0.6 etc until it starts working.  That will help us narrow down the issue.  Also a PrimeFaces Test reproducer would be great so I can debug it.

I can give it a try but I don't think it's related to PrimeFaces in particular. I suspect some wildly setting – but had no luck searching for so far. We've used 12.0.0 with the same effect before.

I've tried to build a minimal example war-file with the same problem and it works as it should. Seems as we have some things mixed up in our ear / war setup – will be hard to find. I'll report back if I find the cause.

It's related to javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING which is set to false in our case. As soon as I enable it, <p:ajax> starts working again. I could reproduce this in my minimal example too. Again... JBoss EAP works with both... Wildfly only with javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING set to true. Is this a known problem of Wildfly v26.1.3?

Use https://github.com/da3x/PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING/ to reproduce it.

This is good stuff let me review and get back to you.

OK its a Mojarra bug.  When I switched from Wildfly to a standalone Jetty I can reproduce the issue with Mojarra 2.3.17 but its fixed in 2.3.18+.
So if you can swap out your Wildfly Mojarra JAR up to the latest 2.3.21 it should be fixed.

Thanks! I'll give this a try till the end of this week.

Wildfly v26.1.3 comes with modules/system/layers/base/com/sun/jsf-impl/main/jsf-impl-2.3.17.SP01.jar – can this be replaced with https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/jakarta.faces/2.3.21 easily? I hope so... the artifactId is changed... the packages hopefully not.

Yes just replace the JAR with 2.3.21 and updated the module.xml file for that. I do it all the time.

It doesn't work for me. If I place the new JAR und reference it like this <resource-root path="jakarta.faces-2.3.21.jar"/> it throws java.lang.VerifyError: Instruction type does not match stack map with Type 'com/sun/faces/application/ValueBindingValueExpressionAdapter' (current frame, locals[2]) is not assignable to 'javax/faces/el/ValueBinding' (stack map, locals[2]) during startup.

Ah... this seems related to my POM: <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId> – trying to clean this up.

I'm not sure anymore... tried to generalize my POMs and it didn't change anything in the end. Maybe it's jboss-jsf-api_2.3_spec-3.1.0.SP01.jar in the wildfly modules? Do I need to change this too?

hhmmmm i have never had a problem upgrading my wildfly in the past....

The real project itself contains references to PrimeFaces und RichFaces and I suspect those RichFaces dependencies to cause these problems. Unfortunately I won't get rid of this old library anytime soon. I'll keep that updated if I make any progress – thanks so far.
